# Finding Towns\Postcodes near specific UK motorway

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I'd like to determine the names\postcodes of all towns near a specific UK motorway, for example - every town\postcode near the M62 in the UK.

Any suggestions how this could be done?

Comment: You have tags for Google Maps, MapServer and Bing Maps. Are you using any of them?  Or are you looking for [softwarerecs.se]?

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify what kind of software you would like to use, but you can do this easily by using QGIS and do a select by location query if you gather the online available source material.

Geographic data for the uk can be downloaded from the government website:
https://data.gov.uk/dataset/7879ab82-2863-401e-8a29-a56e264d2182/major-towns-and-cities-december-2015-boundaries

And I would match this data with motorway/road data from openstreetmaps:
https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html

Comment: Or you could use the OS open highways data